# c ++ - friendship implemetation with method or common function two files

Tags: c++

when I have two .h classes where you have to implement your methods into two corresponding cpps classes.
as it happens in the same file when I have:

```
 class test
 {
    int a;
    int b;
    public:
    friend int sum ();
 };

  int sum ()
  {
     test t;
     t.a = 1;
     t.b = 2;
     return t.a+t.b;
  }
```

if one of the classes declares friendship with the other, will it be implemented as a normal method?
or will it also need to be implemented as a common function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is just one class in this example.

The friend keyword in this example just declares that the external function (in this case `sum`) is allowed to access private attributes/methods of the class that it has friendship with.
It is a normal function, not a method, thus something like this: `test::sum()` or `test t; t.sum()` is not possible.

If you want to access private attributes/methods from this class with another class it works like the following:

```
#include <iostream>

class Test2;

class Test1 {
  int a;
  int b;

  public:
  Test1(int a, int b) : a(a), b(b) {}
  int sum(const Test2& t) const;
};

class Test2 {
  int c;

  public:
  Test2(int c) : c(c) {}
  friend int Test1::sum(const Test2& t) const;
};

int Test1::sum(const Test2& t) const { return a + b + t.c; }

int main()
{
  Test1 t1(2, 4);
  Test2 t2(3);
  std::cout << t1.sum(t2) << std::endl;
  return 0;
}
```

For more and more specific information of the `friend` keyword take a look here:
https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/friend